# Setting up a project with Bootstrap Source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Would anyone be able to shed some light on setting up a project using Bootstrap 3's source?
What does a typical folder structure look like?
Do you link your css/js/etc. to the /dist folder?

I've used Bootstrap in the past but I've always used the precompiled version.

I'm green to compiling things.

Normally with the precompiled, I would add my index files and whatnot to the Bootstrap folder, but with the source code version, this seems a little different.

I've also tried the whole Grunt, Bower, NPM thing and that seemed to cause more headaches than it was worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what you normally do with the default download, then grab the LESS folder from source. Then use a LESS compiler to create your CSS. Something like [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) would do the job without headache. That is pretty much the only benefit to having the source, although for most people it's the fastest way to develop. The LESS variables affect several areas so making a change such as `@brand-primary` can affect links and buttons. Less CSS overrides if you use LESS. Plus, it's easier adding your own custom LESS code in another file.

That method saves you from needing Grunt, but gives you the benefits of using LESS. You might need to tweak the font path, but that's it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'm thinking of setting up (read: learning how to set up) a build script in ST2 to run the LESS compile, and minify all of my stuff.

Comment: I'd **avoid SimpLESS**. Its changelog says it's using Less v1.3.0. The latest Less is v1.7.4. So it sounds super-outdated.

Comment: I said something "like". In other words, a standalone LESS compiler. There are a ton out there. I personally use Grunt.